# JxBrowser Java, Gradle issue

Tags: java, javafx, jxbrowser, javafx-11

When loading my jxBrowser app built in java, using javafx, and using Gradle.

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.java9.platform.PlatformImplMac (in module jxbrowser.javafx) cannot access class com.sun.glass.ui.Window (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.ui to module jxbrowser.javafx
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.java9.platform.PlatformImplMac.findNativeHandle(PlatformImplMac.java:25)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.Platform.doFindNativeHandle(Platform.java:154)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.Platform.nativeHandle(Platform.java:131)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.OffScreenRenderWidget.show(OffScreenRenderWidget.java:303)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.IoSurfaceRenderWidget.show(IoSurfaceRenderWidget.java:88)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.OffScreenRenderWidget.setWindow(OffScreenRenderWidget.java:224)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.OffScreenRenderWidget.access$2000(OffScreenRenderWidget.java:73)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.OffScreenRenderWidget$SceneChangeListener.setScene(OffScreenRenderWidget.java:586)
at jxbrowser.javafx@7.15/com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.OffScreenRenderWidget$SceneChangeListener.lambda$changed$0(OffScreenRenderWidget.java:575)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
```

I don't believe I am missing anything.

I have added all nessasary items in my `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    // The repository for JxBrowser binaries.
    maven { url = 'https://us-maven.pkg.dev/jxbrowser/releases' }
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.7.1'
    jxBrowserVersion = '7.15'
}

dependencies {

    ...
    implementation "com.teamdev.jxbrowser:jxbrowser-win64:${jxBrowserVersion}"
    implementation "com.teamdev.jxbrowser:jxbrowser-mac:${jxBrowserVersion}"
    implementation "com.teamdev.jxbrowser:jxbrowser-javafx:${jxBrowserVersion}"
}
```

I have the VM options needed:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
        "--add-exports", "javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED"
]
```

Any suggestions as to why this error is being displayed?

Comment: I am able to get it to work if I am on version `7.18`. Still not sure why any version lower does not work.

Comment: Just post your solution (use a recent version of JXBrowser) as a self-answer. The system will let you accept the answer in a day or two.

Comment: @jewelsea the only issue is with this newer version. It now breaks my existing logic, so it would be ideal if I can use version `7.15`

Comment: Perhaps try asking the JXBrowser support forum if they have one, perhaps they can help backport a fix for you.

Comment: I was able to get it to work! I simply upgraded to version `7.18` and had to update code based on breaking changes that happened from 7.16 -> 7.17
https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/migration/v7-16-v7-17.html